# Consistent and efficient bi-directional data structure implementation (Java)

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, bidirectional

I needed an implementation of a bi-directional map in Java so I tried to use BiMap and BidiMap from Guava and Commons. However, the inverse view capability is not maintained after a modification on an element. Here is an example with BiMap (same behavior with BidiMap) :

```
BiMap<Set<String>, Set<String>> map = HashBiMap.create();

Set<String> foo = new HashSet<>();
foo.add("foo");

Set<String> bar = new HashSet<>();
bar.add("bar");

map.put(foo, bar);

map.get(foo); // returns [bar], ok
map.inverse().get(map.get(foo)); // returns [foo], ok

map.get(foo).add("someString");

map.get(foo); // returns [bar, someString], ok
map.inverse().get(map.get(foo)); // returns null, not ok <=
```

Of course this behavior can be expected for an implementation using HashMaps but it illustrates the problem.

So the question is, is there a bi-directional data structure which can handle this kind of situation, with elements of arbitrary types, and still have a better average time complexity than an array of pairs?

EDIT : I'm not trying to solve this problem or avoid it, this is more of an academic question. I just want to know if such a data structure exists. That is, a data structure allowing bi-directional binding, mutable keys and with reasonable time complexity.

Comment: Instead of changing the object in the map, or in addition, perhaps you should re-add it to the map to re-adjust the keys.

Comment: Or wrap the `Set<>` in some object that is stable wrt. hashCode & comparability. E.g. simply `class Wrapper { Set<> wrapped = .. }`

Answer (score 3):

Your trouble is not with bidirectional maps, but with the assumption that you are allowed to modify a map key. Keys are in fact fundamentally required to be stable at least regarding the behavior of their `equals` and `hashCode` methods (in case of a hashtable-backed map) or their comparison method (in case of a binary tree-backed map).

Perhaps you can consider removing an element, changing it, then inserting it back—that's one way to meet the constraints of implementation.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not trying to solve this problem or avoid it, this is more of an academic question. I just wanted to know if such a data structure exists. That is, a data structure allowing bi-directional binding, mutable keys and with reasonable time complexity.

Comment: If you mean a structure that can work in spite of its internals being messed with from the outside, then of course it doesn't exist. The structure _must_ know when you're changing the keys---and if it does, then hashtable is already the structure that satisfies your requirement.